# AngularJs Change controller inside a controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router, materialize

I have a homepage where the login and the whole single page app in one html

so I hide the main contents using ng-if please see Index.html

I have a function in my IndexController.js that set true or false for isLogin

Index.html

```
<body ng-controller="IndexController">
<div ng-if="!isLogin">
<!-- contain login codes-->
 <a href="#!Main" ng-click=login()>Login</a>     <!-- login button-->

</div>
<div ng-if="isLogin">

<!-- I have a navbar code here that also needs data from IndexController -->

<section id="content">
  <div ng-view></div>
</section>

</div>
</body>
```

route.js

```
.when("/Main",{
            templateUrl:'views/default.html',
            controller: 'DashboardController'
        })
 .otherwise({
            templateUrl:'views/default.html',
            controller: 'DashboardController}
        );
```

I put the otherwise as that so after I hide the login page the first page that will be loaded in my ng-view will be default.html but the thing is DashboardController is not working unless I click the Dashboard button in my Navbar

so how do I run the dashboard controller after I hide my login page?

Comment: both the template, controller are same. Since this is a single page application it won't get called unless you click on tab. Set it default then

Comment: This is not the right way to handle login/dashboard views generally. Use two different routes for login and dashboard respectively.

Comment: @Lokesh even it is on default. it still don't run